# Aggregating Lags in R

Tags: r, lag

I am trying to find the Yield to Date for a monthly raw data with lag function. Is there a better way to code it instead of the one here? After this I would need to find the YTD for daily data and I believe with the code I have, it will take ages, hence I would need advice on a better way to code it. Thx.

```
YTD<- (lag(Data2,0) + lag(Data2,1) + lag(Data2,2) + lag(Data2,3) +
       lag(Data2,4) + lag(Data2,5) + lag(Data2,6) + lag(Data2,7) +
       lag(Data2,8) + lag(Data2,9) + lag(Data2,10) + lag(Data2,11) +
       lag(Data2,12))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing some or all of `Data2` in a plain text format, and explaining where the `lag` function comes from.

Comment: This is sounding suspiciously like a cumulative sum - see `?cumsum`